# Clicking an element doesn't display a result and chrome dev tools don't show an error

Tags: javascript, html

When you click the `div` it should change `var element` to `var element = 'hidrogeno'` but since it doesn't the other `div` opens with both the `h1` and the `p` elements empty.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

var elemento

function choose(choice) {
  elemento = choice;
}
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

switch (elemento) {
  case 'hidrogeno':
    var title = document.getElementById("header0");
    var info = document.getElementById("text0");
    title.innerHTML = "Hidrogeno";
    info.innerHTML = "El hidr&oacutegeno es el elemento qu&iacutemico de n&uacutemero at&oacutemico 1, representado por el s&iacutembolo H. Con una masa at&oacutemica de 1,00794 (7) u, es el m&aacutes ligero de la tabla de los elementos. Por lo general, se presenta en su forma molecular, formando el gas diat&oacutemico H2 en condiciones normales. Este gas es inflamable, incoloro, inodoro, no met&aacutelico e insoluble en agua."
    break;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtn" class="elem F" onclick=(choose('hidrogeno'))>
  <div class="num">1</div>
  <div class="symbol">H</div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2 id="header0"></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p id="text0"> </p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `elemento` is `undefined` when the `switch` statement is evaluated.

Comment: Looks like just a simple syntax error - should be `onclick="choose('hidrogeno')"`

Comment: @Archer: That's not a syntax error. If it was an error, the OP would get an error message.

Comment: correcting the elemento thing gives `choose is not defined` error

Comment: @GeomanYabes: You're testing in jsFiddle I'm guessing?

Comment: Aside from the `switch` statement, the OP is overwriting the inline `onclick` function with the one assigned to `btn.onclick =...`

Comment: @squint, yes...

Comment: @GeomanYabes: jsFiddle sticks your code inside a function. You need to click the `JavaScript` menu and from the panel choose an option under the `Load Type` menu that doesn't wrap the code.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        //var btnn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        var elemento;

        function choose(choice){
            elemento = choice;
            modal.style.display = "block";  

            switch (elemento) {
            case 'hidrogeno':
            var title = document.getElementById("header0");
            var info = document.getElementById("text0");
            title.innerHTML = "Hidrogeno";
            info.innerHTML = "El hidr&oacutegeno es el elemento qu&iacutemico de n&uacutemero at&oacutemico 1, representado por el s&iacutembolo H. Con una masa at&oacutemica de 1,00794 (7) u, es el m&aacutes ligero de la tabla de los elementos. Por lo general, se presenta en su forma molecular, formando el gas diat&oacutemico H2 en condiciones normales. Este gas es inflamable, incoloro, inodoro, no met&aacutelico e insoluble en agua."
            break;
        }
        }

        // btnn.onclick = function() {
        //  modall.style.display = "block"; 
        // }

        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, you need to remove the `btn.onClick...` in your code as it overrides what you are supposed to be calling in your div click event.

Second, you need to change this

`<div id="myBtn" class="elem F" onclick=(choose('hidrogeno'))>`

to

`<div id="myBtn" class="elem F" onclick="choose( 'hidrogeno')">`

to escape your single quotes.

Third, and the most important. the switch block in your code will not be hit since it will be evaluated on page load where your `elemento` is still undefined. So, you need to put this switch block inside your `choose` function.

***NOTE:*** Do not use switch case if you are only evaluating a single condition, instead, use an `if`. Saves writing time and improves readability. IMO, use it for 3 or more conditions.

**See below snippet:**

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

var elemento;

function choose(choice) {
  //alert(choice);
  elemento = choice;
  modal.style.display = "block";

  //should not use switch if just evaluating only 1 condition
  /*switch (elemento) {
    case 'hidrogeno':
      var title = document.getElementById("header0");
      var info = document.getElementById("text0");
      title.innerHTML = "Hidrogeno";
      info.innerHTML = "El hidr&oacutegeno es el elemento qu&iacutemico de n&uacutemero at&oacutemico 1, representado por el s&iacutembolo H. Con una masa at&oacutemica de 1,00794 (7) u, es el m&aacutes ligero de la tabla de los elementos. Por lo general, se presenta en su forma molecular, formando el gas diat&oacutemico H2 en condiciones normales. Este gas es inflamable, incoloro, inodoro, no met&aacutelico e insoluble en agua."
      break;
  }*/
  if (elemento == 'hidrogeno') {

    var title = document.getElementById("header0");
    var info = document.getElementById("text0");
    title.innerHTML = "Hidrogeno";
    info.innerHTML = "El hidr&oacutegeno es el elemento qu&iacutemico de n&uacutemero at&oacutemico 1, representado por el s&iacutembolo H. Con una masa at&oacutemica de 1,00794 (7) u, es el m&aacutes ligero de la tabla de los elementos. Por lo general, se presenta en su forma molecular, formando el gas diat&oacutemico H2 en condiciones normales. Este gas es inflamable, incoloro, inodoro, no met&aacutelico e insoluble en agua."
  }

}
/*btn.onclick = function() { //this overrides your choice function
  modal.style.display = "block";
}*/

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtn" class="elem F" onclick="choose( 'hidrogeno')">
  <div class="num">1</div>
  <div class="symbol">H</div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">


  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2 id="header0"></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p id="text0"> </p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```